# Некорректная загрузка изображений в ListView из адаптера

Tags: getview, android-sdk, android, listview, java

Есть код, который парсит сайт и добавляет новый элемент в ListView, а в адаптере устанавливаются все данные и загружается изображение. Однако изображения загружаются некорректно (в смысле не те) или в одном элементе поочерёдно проходит несколько изображений, либо вообще не загружаются. При этом никаких исключений не вылетает, а сами ссылки на изображения передаются корректные.

Сам код:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Element> {
      private LayoutInflater mInflater;
      private List<Element> mObjects;
      private ImageView mImage;

      class DownloadBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

            @Override
            protected Drawable doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = new URL(arg0[0]).openConnection().getInputStream();
                    Drawable drawableImg = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
                    is.close();

                    drawableImg.setBounds(0, 0, drawableImg.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawableImg.getIntrinsicHeight());

                    return drawableImg;
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result != null)
                    mImage.setImageDrawable(result);
            }
        }

      public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Element> objects) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

          mObjects = objects;
          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return mObjects.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Element getItem(int position) {
          return mObjects.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View view = convertView;
          if(view == null)
              view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.element, parent, false);

          Element p = getElement(position);

          ((MyTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.header)).setText(p.mName);
          mImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
          new DownloadBitmap().execute(p.mImage);

          return view;
      }

      Element getElement(int position) {
          return getItem(position);
      }
}
```

Comment: в адаптере нужно создать коллекцию которая будет хранить картинки для списка привязанные к позиции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну еще бы: у вас уважаемый загрузка изображений происходит в другом потоке, соответственно если поток загрузки завершился до отрисовки списка показывается правильное изображение, а если нет - то кажет фотку обратной стороны Луны :)

Чтобы работало корректно, надо либо:

1. Читать картинки в getView() в том же потоке
2. Или поступить по совету [@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)
3. А самый верный способ это сделать чтение картинок через `CursorAdapter`